# Executing a stored procedure in mvc4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to execute a insert query in mvc4 on action button,
i have the below action method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(QuestionBank model)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new AdminContext())
                {
                    db.Questions.Add(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            } 

        }
```

I have related model

```
public class QuestionBank

    {
        [Key]
        ////[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string question { get; set; }
    }
```

As we do in simple asp.net application i want to execute that stored procedure on action button.
I don't know whether my approach is right, but please guide me on this.

Comment: Have you tried running it?  Is it not working?

Comment: @Siyual: Ya its not working.

Comment: Define 'not working'.  Other than not having a primary key on your model (one that can autoincrement), I don't see any issues here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you wan't to use the stored procedure approach to execute inserting a question into the database.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(QuestionBank model)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_addQuestion]", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 0 };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("question", model.question) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured });

                    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                //using (var db = new AdminContext())
                //{
                //    db.Questions.Add(model);
                //    db.SaveChanges();
                //}

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            } 

        }
```

Here's the corresponding stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_addQuestion]
    @question nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[QuestionBank] (Question)
        VALUES (@question)

    RETURN @@ERROR;
END
```

Comment: Should i define the connectionstring in the same controller?Is it possible?

Comment: @AniruddhaKPurohit it doesn't really matter, but yeah... most people put it in their app config